# Codeigniter route page using value fetch from database

Tags: codeigniter, routes

currently I have a page like the following -
`abc.com/controller/action/23`
Here 23 is Item id,which is dynamic. I have to fetch the name of the item using the id from database and route to a new url like following -
`abc.com/controller/p/23-itemname`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is when the user visits this page:

```
abc.com/controller/action/23
```

You put this code into the controller

**CONTROLLER**

```
function action()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3); //id is now 23, this is the third uri
    $data['details'] = $this->YOUR_MODEL->get_details($id);
    foreach($data['details'] as $d)
    {
        $itemname = $d->YOUR_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME;
    }
    redirect(base_url(). 'controller/p/' . $id . '-' . $itemname);
    //line produces abc.com/controller/p/23-itemname
}
```

**MODEL**

```
function get_details($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('YOUR_TABLE_NAME');
    $this->db->where('YOUR_ID_COLUMN_NAME',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Just comment if you need more clarifications.

**Goodluck meyt**

**EDIT**

Since you have action and you redirect to function p, here is what will happen.

```
function p()
{
    $explodethis = $this->uri->segment(3); //Contains "23-itemname"
    $pieces = explode("-", $explodethis); //Separate by the dash
    $id = $pieces[0];                     //Contains "23"
    $itemname = $pieces[1];               //Contains "itemname"

    $data['details'] = $this->YOUR_MODEL->YOUR_FUNCTION(YOUR_PARAMETERS)
    $this->load->view('YOUR_VIEW',$data);
}
```

Comment: ok. But I have query . I f I use your code where should I use load view . In action() or in p()?

Comment: so in short, you load it in p since it is the last thing you load, if you try to load in action, it will only show for a short period of time until p is ready then fire p :D

Answer (score 0):

Routing not required to do this. You may generate link by item name

```
<a href="<?php echo  site_url('controller/action').'/'.$val['item_id'].'-'.$val['item_name']; ?>"
```

and now in controller explode this title to get ID of the item and then execute your query

```
$title = explode('-','23-item-name');
$id = trim($title[0]);//this is your item ID
```